# Why when I put delete object link in registrations/edit devise view it always delete account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, destroy

I'm using devise gem and showing user's objects on registrations/edit view.

I have such problem: when I'm clicking delete object link - it destroy user record, but should delete object.

User has many websites, so I show user his websited and want user available to delete it using this code:

```
<% @websites.each do |website| %>  
  <%unless current_user.websites.empty? %>
    <%= link_to 'X', website_path(website), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>      
<% end %>
```

Controller code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    @websites = current_user.websites
    @reports = current_user.financial_reports
  end
end

class WebsitesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @website = Website.find(params[:id])
    if (current_user.id != @website.user_id)
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = 'You are not owner!'
    else
      @website.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to websites_url }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I didn't change anything in standard behavior in Websites_controller.

Can someone suggest how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you paste your websites_controller code?

Comment: @Deepak, destroy action only ?

Comment: The action which loads this view you have mentioned above and the destroy action of the websites_controller.

Comment: It would be worth checking, or pasting in, your associations. Do you have `:dependent => :destroy` on the wrong end of the association?

Comment: @Shadwell, it seems that you are right... Forgot about this. Thanks! Post answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be worth checking your associations. If you have `:dependent => :destroy` on the wrong end of the association between users and websites then destroying the website would cause the associated user to be destroyed too.